# dojo/dijit BorderContainer declarative example - but programmatic

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm trying to write the declarative example in a programmatic way, but so far no success.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html

```
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    var borderContainer = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({
        design: "sidebar",
        gutters: true,
        liveSplitters: true,
        id: "borderContainer"
    });

   borderContainer.placeAt(dojo.body(), "last");

    var panelLeft = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        content: "<p>left</p>",
        splitter: true,
        region: "leading",
        style: "width: 300px;"
    });
    panelLeft.placeAt("borderContainer", "first");

    var panelRight = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        content: "<p>right</p>",
        splitter: true,
        region: "center"
    });
    panelRight.placeAt("borderContainer", "last");

});
```

CSS file: `#borderContainer { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

You can see the code here: http://jsbin.com/inulig/27/edit#source

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so this amuses me but this happens a lot of times. After I ask it somewhere I usually find the answer too. And I did tried to do it on my own, I work on it several hours. I found http://blog.garethj.com/2010/08/programmatic-page-layouts-using-dojo-and-existing-markup/ which gave me a lead to the issue. I had to use `borderContainer.addChild(contentPane)` and not `contentPane.placeAt(...)`. I'll leave the answer here in case other might get stumbled upon this too. [[ I can't post my own answer ]]

Comment: Sure, you can post your own answer. Others can post more answers as well and the best answers will hopefully be voted up.

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait 8 hours since posting the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found http://blog.garethj.com/2010/08/programmatic-page-layouts-using-dojo-and-existing-markup/ which gave me a lead to the issue.

I had to use `borderContainer.addChild(contentPane)` and not `contentPane.placeAt(borderContainer, "last")`

I'll leave the answer here in case other might get stumbled upon this too.

Answer (score 1):

```
borderContainer.addChild(contentPane);
borderContainer.startup(); //DO NOT FORGET TO STARTUP!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

DO THIS:   contentPane.placeAt(borderContainer.domNode, "last");